# Accessing LAN resources from WLAN using SonicWALL TZ 215 wireless-N

Tags: networking, sonicwall, wlan

I'm trying to allow clients connected to my SonicWALL's wireless network to connect to computers on the wired LAN. I am aware that this is a security risk.

I set up the firewall to allow the connection as shown in the screenshot, but wireless clients still cannot connect. Is this an issue because they aren't on the same network (WLAN: 172.X.X.X; LAN 192.X.X.X)? Do I have to set up a route between them to get this to work?

[image]

EDIT:

tried editing some settings in the zones area, but still a no-go

[image]
[image]

X0 settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Weird, that rule should be enough to make it work, the required routes are automatically created in the Sonicwall for trusted interfaces. Is the `Allow Interface Trust` option enabled in the WLAN Zone?

Try starting from the step 2 on this document.

[Sonicwall UTM - Wireless: How to allow TCP communications between Wireless (Authenticated to SonicPoints) and Wired Hosts connected to the same network without using Layer2 bridge Mode.](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw8334)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I added the `Interface Trust` and unchecked `Only allow traffic generated by a SonicPoint...` as per the knowledge base article but clients still don't have access to the X0 network from W0.

Comment: Hmm.. What about the logs, try leaving any host on the W0 network running ping against a host in the X0 network and go to Log > View, check if whatever is preventing the traffic is shown there. Also, you can temporarily disable the security services in LAN and WLAN zones for troubleshooting (IPS, App Control.. )

Comment: nothing interesting in the logs... disabling security services didn't seem to do anything either. I guess I have to call up Dell. I'll post the solution here. Thanks again. Happy New Year.

Comment: Good luck! Happy New Year!

Comment: urls go nowhere useful

Answer (score 1):

L2 Bridged mode will accomplish what you want.  This will allow the LAN and WLAN to be on the same subnet with a shared pool of addresses as with a typical "home" wireless router.  I got the same thing: "Error: Index of the interface.: Portshield interfaces can not be assigned to L2 bridge pair" when attempting to bridge the two.  Here is the solution:

https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw11470

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having now, is that DNS and Netbios.  You should be able to connect via IP address.  Computer name will not work since Netbios does not broadcast beyond local subnet.  You could avoid this if you setup WLAN as a layer 2 bridge mode, that way your LAN and WLAN are on the same subnet.  Otherwise you will need to setup a DNS server or create local hosts files on all your machines.

Answer (score -1):

Go under **Firewall** > **Access Rules** and change **WLAN > LAN** from **Deny** to **Allow**. This will correct the problem for you.

Comment: It looks like this is how it already is...?